# Custom component Android LinearLayout not visible

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

Custom LinearLayout component view not displaying content

Hi i have created a custom component view that extends LinearLayout and when i use this view on my xml, it doesnt become visible on the screen.

Here is the main view that is using this custom component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contentLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ABB0B6" />

    <com.jon.ui.EnableView
        android:id="@+id/enableContainter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the EnableView custom component code:

```
package com.jon.ui;



/**
 */
public class EnableView extends LinearLayout {

    private static View enableView;

    private static Button btnContactlessInfoAction;
    private static LinearLayout btnMakeContactlessAction;
    private static View makeContactlessView;


    private static View.OnClickListener enableContaclessBtnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };

    private static View.OnClickListener contactlessHelpBtnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };
    private static ViewGroup viewContainer;
    private final Context mContext;

    public EnableContactlessView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_component, this);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    }

    public EnableContactlessView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_component, this);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

    }

    public void initiate() {

           btnMakeContactlessAction = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            btnContactlessInfoAction = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.info_btn);
            btnContactlessInfoAction.setOnClickListener(contactlessHelpBtnClick);


    }




    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    }
}
```

Below is the 
View's layout xml i use to inflate from EnableView class called custom_component.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/button_colour"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="9dp">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_symbol" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="activate and enable"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info_btn"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:background="@drawable/icon" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not override onLayout if you're leaving it empty, remove that function. onLayout is used to measure the parent and its children, if you leave it empty nothing is getting measured.